# Google calendar doesn't refresh data from Trello

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, trello

I set up Trello board, added iCal function. Added link to the Google Calendar. After I'm adding functions to Google calendar it shows me latest data, but as soon as I update data - Google calendar doesn't make any changes. I waited for 2 days and results are same. How to make Google calendar able to see changes? Or is this problem comes from Trello?

Answer (score 0):

I only know a workaround. Go to calendar settings and change the URL - actually remove and add the same calendar with a substring which makes Google treat the calendar as a new feed.

Example: .../my_calendar.ics -> .../my_calendar.ics?noCache (or any string instead of 'noCache'). I have tested, works with different types (e.g. for MeisterTask needed to add &noCache).

I have found the answer [here](https://www.binarysludge.com/2012/02/01/how-to-force-refresh-google-calendar/).